# CSS/HTML link on header and size

Tags: html, css

I don't know what I've done wrong, for some reason the "contact and location" button doesn't align, Also I cannot figure out how to make the bottom header's `height` lower or how to make the wood `header` background have more `height`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Vintage Wine & Liquor</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">
</head>

<body>


  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="header">
      <img class="logo" src="managed/logo.png" width="727" height="61" alt="Vintage Wine & Liquor" />



    </div>
    <div class="navmain">
      <ul>

        <a href="http://www.google.com">
          <img src="managed/home.png">
        </a>

        <a href="#">
          <img src="managed/inventory.png">
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="managed/contact.png" align="texttop">
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</body>

</html>
```

**desired result**

[image: SS]

**Result**

[image: SS]

Comment: Please provide .css for this code and upload it on jsfiddle. And are you really using images for the text? Hmm..

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things wrong with your code

- you are using `align="texttop"` in the last image and that's causing the the misalignment, so remove it.
- the `ul` can only have `li` as direct child, otherwise the **HTML IS INVALID**
- don't use `width/height` HTML tags, instead use CSS properties to style it.

```css
body,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    <img class="logo" src="//lorempixel.com/727/61" alt="Vintage Wine & Liquor" />
  </div>
  <div class="navmain">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://www.google.com">
          <img src="//lorempixel.com/30/30">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="//lorempixel.com/30/30">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="//lorempixel.com/30/30">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```